# Docker Swarm. How to connect to container running on worker node from the manager node?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I need copy some files from the container running on worker node to manager host.
This operation I need to do staying on manager.

In other words how to access to the container running on worker node from manager?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible (with pure `Docker` operations). When you create a service in your `swarm` which is running on a `worker node` then a simple `Docker container` will be started by `Docker` on that `node`. That `container` has to be used to copy in/out files (The `service` is accessible from `manager node(s)` (Eg.: `logs` cmd) but the `container` itself is not)!

**You can simply verify it:**

If you run the following command to get the `container` ID based on the `service` name you can get the `container` ID(s) on the actual `node` (That means you will be able to connect to the `container` from actual (`manager`) `node`)

```
docker ps -q -f name=<service_name>
```

If one of `<service_name>`'s replicas run on the actual server then you will get a `Docker Container ID` and you can connect it. Eg.:

```
>>> docker ps -q -f name=test_swarm_service
b1ae9e0991ef
```

If there is not running `replica` on the actual `node`, you will get nothing from the command, that means you won't be able to connect to it from actual node.

If you are sure that one of `replicas` runs on the actual `node` you can copy files from `container` (via `Swarm service`'s name) like that:

```bash
docker cp $(docker ps -q -f name=<servicename>):/inside/path/ /local/path
```

Of course, you can do it from your `manager node(s)` with some hacking (Not pure `Docker`). Eg.:

- [Run the `Docker` command via `SSH`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/) (from `manager node` on `worker node`) and copy the file(s) from `worker node` to `manager node` via [scp](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/) or [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).